# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed navigation drawer example

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to create navigation drawer using drawer layout as per android tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

It works fine if I just create one class MainActivity and add DrawerItemClickListener class as inner class.

But if I add DrawerItemClickListener as new class in same package I get error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed. I extended DrawerItemClickListener to MainActivity to get rid of error 'resolve method getFragmentManager()' and 'getActionBar()'. This is the only difference when I put as outer class instead of inner class. 
Here is snippet for code same as tutorial:

```
public class DrawerItemClickListener extends MainActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
    /**
     * Swaps fragments in the main content view
     */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position

        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }


    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use new operator on the class which extends Activity... Obviously, problem is that you are extending Activity... obviously you should pass (to constructor or via some set method) Activity instead

Comment: so I shouldn't extend to MainActivity or ActionBarActivity? If I don't do that I get error error 'resolve method getFragmentManager()' and 'getActionBar()'. How do I pass to constructor?

Comment: Via parameter...  And those methods should be called on instance of ActionBarActivity passed to this class...

Comment: do you mind giving the example I'm not getting hang of it